# Dynamic dispatch and access level of a method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, dynamic-dispatch

Consider the following classes:

```
public class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A.foo()");
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("A.bar()");
        foo();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B.foo()");
    }

    public static void main(String[]
    args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.bar();
    }
}
```

The output of this code is `A.bar()` and then `B.foo()`. I've noticed that if I change the method foo()'s access level from `public` to `private` the output is: `A.bar()` and then `A.foo()`.

Why?

Comment: Because `private` methods aren't inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `A.foo()` is private, then it can't be overridden by a subclass - any other class should basically be unaware of the existence of private members. You can't override a member you can't "see".

From [section 8.4.8.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method m<sub>C</sub> declared in or inherited by class `C`, overrides from `C` another method m<sub>A</sub> declared in class `A`, iff all of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - m<sub>A</sub> is public.
>   - m<sub>A</sub> is protected.
>   - m<sub>A</sub> is declared with package access in the same package as `C`, and either `C` declares m<sub>C</sub> or m<sub>A</sub> is a member of the direct superclass of `C`.
>   - m<sub>A</sub> is declared with package access and m<sub>C</sub> overrides m<sub>A</sub> from some superclass of `C`.
>   - m<sub>A</sub> is declared with package access and m<sub>C</sub> overrides a method m' from `C` (m' distinct from m<sub>C</sub> and m<sub>A</sub>), such that m' overrides m<sub>A</sub> from some superclass of `C`.